# AWS WAF Create an ACL and rule to allow access to only one country to access the API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I want to create a json format cloud formation template that creates an ACL and rule in WAF to allow only the United States users to access the API gateway. I have the following code so far but it gives an error ("Encountered unsupported property Action") in AWS:

```
        "Type":"AWS::WAF::Rule",
        "Properties":{
            "Name":"APIGeoBlockRule",
            "Priority":0,
            "Action":{
                "Block":{}
            },
            "VisibilityConfig":{
                "SampledRequestsEnabled":true,
                "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled":true,
                "MetricName": "APIGeoBlockRule"
            },
            "Statement":{
                "NotStatement":{
                    "Statement":{
                        "GeoMatchStatement":{
                            "CountryCodes":[
                                "US"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking to use the classic WAF or WAFv2? Also are you using cloudfront?

Comment: The documented properties of (v1) AWS::WAF::Rule are MetricName, Name, and Predicates.

Comment: I am using WAF and not the WAF classic

Comment: Can someone give a code based example? There is very little documentation from AWS on clouf formation template.

Comment: I am using WAFv2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the documentation, you are trying to do a WAFv2 rule under a classic WAF resource. Your resource type of `AWS::WAF::Rule` is the classic WAF rule while the structure is of WAFv2.

I haven't used WAFv2 yet myself but looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html), this should be about what you want in yaml format:

```
Description: Create WebACL example
Resources:
  ExampleWebACL:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      Name: ExampleWebACL
      Scope: REGIONAL
      Description: This is an example WebACL
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {}
      Rules:
        - Name: GeoRestrictExample
          Priority: 0
          Action:
            Block: {}
          Statement:
            NotStatement:
              Statement:
                GeoMatchStatement:
                    CountryCodes:
                      - US
```

As of 1/13/2020, you cannot associate a resource such as api gateway stage with a WAFv2 ACL using cloudformation. You can do so using the console, sdk, a custom resource, and [cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/associate-web-acl.html).

Comment: The issue with this option is that you cannot associate a resource such as an API gateway to the WAF ACL, we need to use WAF regional for this purpose. I am looking for a sample code that implements WAF regional. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafregional-webacl.html

Comment: That documentation looks to be for the WAF classic. For waf classic, the different ACLs for global vs region were distinct, but in the the waf they are the same. If you look at my example code, you will see that the region is defined in the scope. It's unfortunate that the documentation is very confusing.

Comment: Looking further in the documentation, it looks like the classic waf had a resource called `AWS::WAFRegional::WebACLAssociation` that could have been used, but the newer WAFv2 does not have such a cloudformation resource as of today. You can still do it from the console, sdk, and [cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/associate-web-acl.html), but I think they haven't added to cloudformation yet. Cloudformation sometimes has a delay release making it difficult to adopt new features.

Comment: I have reached out to aws support and they have confirmed that there is no way currently to associate an api gateway to a WAFv2 ACL using cloudformation. They have it on their roadmap, but they do not have a current ETA.

Comment: You can now associate with an API gateway. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webaclassociation.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be solved when Cloudformation implements WAFv2 (which they recommend you use now). Ultimately we need Cloudformation to support creation and association (i.e. to an API Gateway or Load Balancer) so that other workarounds aren't put in place as they're not very transferable.

The GitHub ticket is: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/344